# Wrap each digitand prepend zeros up to X digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a possibility to wrap each character in Javascript and prepend zero's if its less then X digits?

What i get/have:

```
var votes = 2;
//or
var votes = 123;
//or
var votes = 4321;
```

what it should to look like:

```
<span>0</span><span>0</span><span>0</span><span>2</span>
//or
<span>0</span><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>
//or
<span>4</span><span>3</span><span>2</span><span>1</span>
```

so the result should be a number with four digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's a tricky version:

```
var votes = 123;
("0000" + votes).slice(-4); /* 0123 */
```

---

thus, to wrap each digit in a `<span>` you could fetch each digit with `$.map` and wrap it into its own element, like in this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cZAWj/

```
var votes = 973;

$.map(("0000" + votes).slice(-4), function(digit) {
    $('<span/>', { text : digit }).appendTo($('body'));
});
```

Comment: this looks freaking nice and smart... but i dont get as im a bit noob -.- nevermind is there a way now to also wrap each digit with a html tag like a span?

Comment: merci for the fast solution... this saved me alot of time :) i will check this as the right answer

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, make it look like a string and pad it...

```
   function pad(number, length) {      
        var str = '' + number;
        while (str.length < length) {
            str = '0' + str;
        }       
        return str;
    }
```

Then you can iterate over it and add a span around each number. Then write the markup out as the .html of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Well one way to do it would be to convert the number to a string and pre-append 0 until we reach the desired length.

So if you want `X` digits:

```
var strNb = "" + nb;
while (strNb.length < X){
  strNb = "0" + strNb
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatNumber(d, x) {
    var l = String(d).length;
    return (l<x?(Array(x-l).join('0') + d):String(d)).replace(/\d/g,"<span>$&</span>");
}
```